# Re-export ES6 import namespace in a single statement?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I currently have this in my `index.js` which works:

```
import * as tmp from './actions';
export const myActions = tmp;
```

However, I find it quite ugly that I have to assign the namespace to a temporary variable first.

Is there any way to use a single `export ... from ...;` statement to do the same?

Note that I do not want to modify `actions.js` - I know that it's possible to just export an object from a module and then use that...

---

I know about `export * from ...` but that's not what I'm looking for since my module exports other things as well which I don't want to merge with the exported actions.

Comment: How about this:  `export { * as tmp } from './actions'`

Comment: @PraveshKhatri That's a syntax error, both with and without the curly braces. It's actually the first thing I tried even before asking the question ;)

Comment: Don't use a temporary variable. Do `import * as myActions from './actions';
export { myActions }`.